# how boost generate an unique name for interprocess_mutex on windows

Tags: c++, windows, boost, ipc, mutex

```cpp
// boost/interprocess/sync/windows/sync_utils.hpp
void* open_or_create_mutex(const sync_id &id)
{
    NameBuf name;
    fill_name(name, id);
    permissions unrestricted_security;
    unrestricted_security.set_unrestricted();
    winapi_mutex_wrapper mtx_wrapper;
    mtx_wrapper.open_or_create(name, unrestricted_security);
    throw_if_error(mtx_wrapper.handle());
    return mtx_wrapper.release();
}
```

The `sync_id` is initialized with the result of the `QueryPerformanceCounter` call, for example:

```cpp
LARGE_INTEGER counter;
QueryPerformanceCounter(&counter);
sync_id = counter.QuadPart;
```

And the `name` is generated by `sync_id`:

```cpp
name = "Global\\boost.ipc" + hex_string(sync_id);
```

How boost make a unique "name" with above algorithm? the `sync_id` is an `int64_t` value, it seems that may not be an unique value.

Answer (score 0):

The name is used as given. It's not supposed to be unique. The whole point of interprocess synchronization primitives is that they do not get unique names in order to be accessible from different processes.

If you want private mutexes, use Boost Thread mutex or std::mutex (there are timed/shared versions).

Comment: But why boost use timestamp to generate the name instead of guid?
For example, there are 4 programs installed in one comptuer, the ProgramA0 and ProgramA1 are designed by CompanyA and  do some interprocess synchronization with boost::interprocess_mutex， the ProgramB0 and ProgramB1 are designed by CompayB and do some interprocess synchronization with boost::interprocess_mutex too. In above case, it's may failed when ProgramB* create the mutex because the "name " is used by ProgramA*.

Comment: Oh. You never said that the performance timer was in _boost_ code - I assumed you wrote that. I'll have to go find it. In general, always say what *end-user facing interface* you use.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong implementation details. The sync_id is only used to map object identity to a corresponding windows sync handle (via `windows_intermodule_singleton<sync_handles>::get()`). Notably, the synic_id *IS* object identity - only enriched with "time based random", presumably to guard against races when a new sync primitive is keyed to the same mapped_address at a later time in the same address space. This `sync_id` has nothing to do with the name given by the user. It's not even about named mutexes in the first place.

Comment: What it comes down to is that the singleton handle registry is used so you can have pthread style semantics for synchronization objects, where the ***object identity*** identifies the Windows kernel handle, precisely like it would on e.g. Linux. The timebased addition is only there to make sure that reused addresses over time don't collide.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't understand "You're looking at the wrong implementation details", the sync_id is used to map object, and it also used to generated the name for create mutex, in sync_handles::obtain_mutex(), it call the open_or_create_mutex to create the mutex, the name is initialized in the fill_name call, fill_name will return `"Global\\boost.ipc" + bytes_to_str(sync_id.rand_);`, the name will passed to CreateMutexA as the third argument, it must be an unique name.